# Ошибка file_get_contents()

Tags: php, apache

Функция тянет страницу из сети

```
Message: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
```

Есть предположение, что тут замешаны настройки в php.ini или apache с запретом на подгрузку данных из сторонних сервисов.

Comment: ЗАбудь эту функцию!!!!!!!! ЧТОБЫ она работала - нада чтоб ее разрешили на сервере откуда тянутся данный!!!  Юзай cURL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$pageSource = curl_exec($ch); // <---
curl_close($ch);
```